# Maven repository error

Tags: apache, maven

This error started coming up few days back when codehaus repository got terminated. I am not sure if this is coming due to that or some other issue. Please help. While this jar and pom exists in my internal repository.

Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolutionException: Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-
api_1.0_spec:jar': Cannot find parent: org.apache.geronimo.genesis.config:config for project: null:project-config:pom:1.1 for project null:project-config:pom:1.1
  org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.1

Comment: can you share your `pom.xml`

Comment: The codehaus repository shouldn't have to do anything with your build. If it's really causing problems than your configuration is simply wrong...but as already mentioned without pom file it's hard to guess what's wrong.